# How do I use regular expressions to match a word with boundaries?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have this string: `"http://www.google.com/this_is_our_network/"`

I want to match against the word "work" but with no alphabetic character in the start or in the end. In the above example the regex should not return a match.

But, in this string: `"http://www.google.com/work_for_us.html"` the regex should come up with a match since there is no alphabetic character in the start nor in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex: `(?<=[\W_])work(?=[\W_])`

This uses *positive look-ahead and look-behind assertions* to respect enclosing characters but without including them in the match.

This regex matches `work`

1. if it follows a `\W` character or an underscore

   AND
2. if it is followed by a `\W` character or an underscore.

`\b` for word boundary matching can't be used since `_` matches `\w` which is not wanted here.

---

Further examples:

- Matching multiple words:
  `(?<=[\W_])(work|job)(?=[\W_])`
- Same as above but without creating submatches:
  `(?<=[\W_])(?:work|job)(?=[\W_])`
- Also respecting line end:
  `(?<=[\W_])(?:work|job)(?=[\W_]|$)`

---

Some useful notes regarding regex syntax:

- `\w` matches all alphanumeric characters and underscore; this is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\W` matches the exact opposite of `\w`
- `\b` matches boundaries between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vise-versa)
- *Positive look-ahead assertion:*
  `foo(?=bar)` matches `foo` followed by `bar`, without including `bar` in the match.
- *Positive look-behind assertion:*
  `(?<=foo)bar` matches `bar` if it follows `foo`, without including `foo` in the match.

For further information on (python) regex syntax consider the [python regex docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) or the [perl regex docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Also, the web-based [Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/) is handy for testing.

Comment: Thanks - this did the trick.
It would be nice if you could explain it bit further.

Comment: How do I extend it to support multiple words: for example work or job.
I've tried using the | separator - but this did not make it.

Comment: @user1537701 For multiple matches `|` will work, but you need to group the words with round brackets: `(?<=[\W_])(work|job)(?=[\W_])`. Note that this creates a submatch. If you don't want a submatch, use `(?<=[\W_])(?:work|job)(?=[\W_])`.

Comment: @speakr - 10x - you did it once again, :)

Comment: @speakr - could you please refine it to include an option where there is no right delimiter for example: "http://www.google.com/this_is_our_work"

Comment: @user1537701 I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: @speakr - I've been struggling with patching the regular expression you've provided to respect start with those words - for example
career.asp
Help is highly appreciated.